# Subclassing view and onDraw()

Tags: android

I have two images,One image will be static meaning it will not move at all,another image a 10*10 circle will need to move to exact pixels on top of the other image.Doing some research I see I need to override the onDraw() method.Although I could not really find any sample code to get me started.

So what I am asking is a link to a good tutorial or some help getting started.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a brief overview from the Android Developer site that should give you some background information.

developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html#draw-with-canvas

Also, if you go here you can see my code for drawing a Graph. It'll give you some examples of other methods you can use.  The onDraw() method is at line # 444.  Keep in mind you need to call invalidate() every time you want the view to call on Draw.

http://code.google.com/p/calculus-tools/source/browse/DerivativeLibrary/src/com/andymc/derivativelibrary/GraphView.java

Answer (score 0):

The Android API demos are full of great examples. They're on your local computer in the Android SDK under "samples/". You can also see them online. The "graphics" subsection in particular has lots of examples with Views that override onDraw.

As a random example, check out [DrawPoints.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/DrawPoints.html).